# too many open files c

Tags: c, file

I have been trying to create a simple program. However, I encountered an error:

> gmon.out:too many open files

I am not clear on why it says I have "too many open files". It does not appear I am using files.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct position
{
    int line;
    int place;
    struct position *next;
};
struct file
{
    struct position *info;
    struct file *next;
    char *name;
};
struct word
{
    char *name;
    struct word *right;
    struct word *left;
    struct file *result;
};

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct word *d,*c;
    char *s="brutus";
    printf("%s",s);
    c=(struct word*)malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    strcpy(c->name,s);
    c->left=NULL;
    c->right=NULL;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        d=(struct word*)malloc(sizeof(struct word));
        if(d==NULL)
            exit(0);

        scanf("%s",s);
        printf("4");
        s=d->name;

        printf("%s",d->name);

        d->left=NULL;
        d->right=NULL;
    }
    system("pause");
    exit(0);
}
```

What should I do about it?Thank you in advnace for your time!

Comment: No allocation of `s` ... the memory will be corrupted when `scanf` is called.

Comment: @Al.Sal Please have a look at this  post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links

Comment: Important, yet unrelated remark: [Do not cast the return value of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Comment: I don't mind at all if people cast the return value of malloc. C++ developers do it all the time, so I'd want to hear a good reason what's bad about it, assuming a decent development system.

Comment: I added s=(char*)malloc(20*sizeof(char)); but still,it doesn't work...Thank you for your time though...!

Comment: @gnasher729: Read the link. In C++, you _have_ to cast the pointer. C != C++, though. using `some_ptr = malloc(10 *sizeof *some_ptr);` is the C-way, if you will. You're free to change the type of `some_ptr`, without having to worry about the memory-management functions at all, simply because you're using `sizeof *some_ptr`. Think about custom allocators and such: `void * my_malloc(void **some_var, size_t size_type, size_t multiplier) { *some_var = realloc(*some_var, multiplier*size_type); if (*some_var == NULL) return null; return *some_var;}` try that without casts.

Comment: @user3697730: `char *s` is actually a `const char *s`, because you've assigned a string literal: that string is stored in _read-only_ memory

Comment: Well,it seems that you are right...!I added everwhere some mallocs and now it works...!Thanks a lot!!I had been trying to solve this problem for hours...!I am still a beginner at programming unfortunately...Willem M and gnasher729,you both helped a lot...For this reason,I cannot choose to vote one of your answeres..Thank you though!

Comment: From now on,I will be using mallocs everywhere,just to make sure that I won't face similar problems...Even when they are not needed!

Comment: @user3697730: Please read through the help section of this site: you're requested not to leave _"thank you"_ comments. Instead mark the answer that helped you the best as accepted. I've bundled all of my comments + more details into an answer, because these comments only addressed half of the issues you had

Answer (score 2):

First off:

> gmon.out:too many open files

Means that you're compiling with the `-p` flag (profiling). gmon.out is the default file-name used by gprof. Just ditch-the-switch, and you won't get that problem anymore.
Of course, not profiling code isn't great, but you'd do well to address a coupe of issues first, before setting about actually profiling your code.

Some of these, quite numerous, issues are:

```
char *s="brutus";
printf("%s",s);
c=(struct word*)malloc(sizeof(struct word));
strcpy(c->name,s);
```

List of issues:

- `char *s` should be `const char *s`, because it points to read-only memory.
- Next, [Do not cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)
- Check the return value of functions like `malloc`, they tell you something
- `struct word`is a struct of which all members are pointers. After allocating the struct, those pointers are invalid: you need to allocate memory for those members, too
- `strcpy` expects the destination (`c->name`) to be a valid pointer, as I explained above: this is not the case here

What, then, should this code look like:

```
const char *s = "brutus";
c = malloc(sizeof *c);
if (c == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate memory for struct word\n");
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
//allocate enough memory to store the string
c->name = malloc(
    (strlen(s)+1) * sizeof *c->name
);
//OR same, but shorter, works because the type char is guaranteed by the standard to be 1 byte in size
c->name = malloc(strlen(s)+1);
if (c->name == NULL)
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );//could not allocate mem
c->name[0] = '\0';//set to empty string, now we can use safer functions:
strncat(c->name, s, strlen(s));
```

After you address these issues, seriously re-think your approach, and ask yourself what it is you're actually trying to do here:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
{
    d=(struct word*)malloc(sizeof(struct word));
    if(d==NULL)
        exit(0);

    scanf("%s",s);
    printf("4");
    s=d->name;
}
```

You're allocating a struct 10 times, each time re-assigning it to `d`. You never free this memory, though. which is bad practice.
Again: *don't cast the return of `malloc`*, but that's the least of your worries.

```
if (d == NULL)
    exit(0);
```

Ok, now you check the return of `malloc`. Great. But why on earth are you terminating with *0* (indicative of a successful run). There's a macro for this, too. You could've written:

```
if (d == NULL)
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Clearly, `EXIT_SUCCESS` is not what you should communicate.
that `const char *s` is now being used to store user input. That's not going to work, though, as it points to *read-only* memory, so forget about the unsafe `scanf("%s", s);` statement. Use a stack variable, and make sure the input buffer is cleared, or use a safe alternative.
But then you go and do something as absurd as this:

```
s = d->name;
```

Again, `d->name`, like in the case with `c`, is an invalid pointer. Why assign it to `s` here? there's no point, no reason... only madness.

Bottom line: Kill this code before it hatches, start again, and please use these tips/recommendations and critiques as a guideline.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you're getting a 'too many open files', but this line:

```
strcpy(c->name,s)
```

is writing data to random memory, which could cause all kinds of problems.
You need to malloc() that c->name first.

Also that scanf to s looks suspicious, and d->name is never assigned anything either.

The reason that you're getting 'too many open files' is probably because some memory is getting overwritten in such a way that just happens to trigger that particular error.  Welcome to the world of undefined behaviour.  IE: If you overwrite random memory, basically *anything* can happen.

Answer (score 0):

The first bug is in the line

```
    strcpy(c->name,s);
```

At that point, c->name is an uninitialised pointer so the program will crash if you are lucky.

Reading your comment: You fixed the second bug. The first bug is still unfixed. And there's the third bug in the line

```
    s=d->name;
```

Answer (score 0):

This string copy will run off through memory, starting at whatever c->name points to until it finds a null terminator.

strcpy(c->name,s);

You have allocated space for c but not for the name pointer in c.

c->name = malloc([some length]);

c->name points somewhere, but you don't know where until you malloc it. That's why you're getting a seemingly random error, because your executing a string copy from an unknown location for an unknown number of bytes and you are clobbering whatever s points to for an unknown number of bytes.